# Facebook login in Android and store user info locally

Tags: android

Hi I am new in android development. My requirement is to login with facebook in Android and store user info in locally. How can I implement Facebook login in android?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through this link 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

and follow the step. This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

To login with facebook use this link

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

and when login success event get user profile(data)  and store in SharedPreferences or local database as per your requirements.